# Use NFC to create contact

Tags: android, nfc, contacts

Can you please help me write an app which on tapping an NFC sticker write data such as Name, Mobile and Email. Once user reads the NFC it should open the save to contacts option with all data pre-filled in.

I am using NDEF plain/text format. Am I headed in the right direction ?

Cheers,
Ishwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real need to write an app for that. When tapping an NFC tag with an NDEF message with the MIME type "text/vcard" and payload data formatted according to the [vCard standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), the vCard data will automatically be imported into the contacts app.